# How to create connection in an folder (mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my situation i just want to create a connection but in a folder.

This is my code :

```
export const connectionAvatar = mongoose.createConnection(
  'mongodb://localhost:27017/file/audio', // I think mongo don't let me to create the folder audio
  options
)
```

I can create my connection if I use only 'mongodb://localhost:27017/file', but I really have to manage all my data in audio files.

When I start my console, the error is :

```
MongoError: database names cannot contain the character '/'
```

Comment: I'm guessing `file` is the database name and `audio` is a collection in the database yeah?

Comment: Thank you but no, I want an audio folder in my file. Cause my file will be separated between a lot a contents. My english is really bad but I need something like this : file>audio>audio.file

Comment: I see you are talking about files and folders. I don't think MongoDB is what you need, MongoDB is a NoSQL database that stores data using collections and documents.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I try to found another solution to skip this folder